# How to use LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid in scrollable column in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am trying to use LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid in scrollable column in jetpack compose but the app is crashing

I tried using vertical scroll in column and it but my grid on it's content but the app crash
.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're gonna have to specify a height for inside scrollable.

If you don't want to set a fixed height and it's alright to take as much as needed from the screen, then you can give it `weight`:

```
Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            ...
    ){
    ...
    LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            ...
    ){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: set height work but weight(1f) not showing the grid